# Zend Framework 2 Routing

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I am having a problem with getting my routes to work properly.

In my backend I have a module calles Pages in which the user can create custom pages with the content they want.

The url's are like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/name-of-page/5/p
http://www.domain.com/name-of-page2/24/p
http://www.domain.com/pagename/10/p
```

At first I have the page name which is dynamic
The second value is the id of the page which I use to get the correct page back.
The last value is " p " which I wanna use as an indentifier for the route so it knows its a page

```
          'p' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:name][/:id]/:p',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Page\Controller\Frontend',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Oops of course, I checked the code like a twenty times but didn't saw the obvious....

Comment: Your route still matches `http://domain.com//p` if you don't change it ;) And you'd run into an error in this case I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First off, my suggestion is to make the page-uri-identifier prepending rather apending. Second of all, understand that `:foo` is a parameter called `foo`. On the other hand `[:foo]` is an **optional** parameter called `foo`.

Boiling it down, i think your route definition should look like this:

```
'route'       => '/p[/:name]/:id',
'constraints' => array(
    'name' => '[\d\w]+', // [a-zA-Z-0-9_]+
    'id'   => '\d+'
)
```

This would match the following routes:

- http://domain.foo/p/1
- http://domain.foo/p/my-page-name/1

You would **not** be able to have a "page-route" without an **ID** but you would be able to have a "page-route" withotu a **name**. Ultimately all that's needed is the ID anyways. Of course you could easily change the order, but it's my personal belief that this is the best solution ;)